# I have expired problems with LikeExpression in hibernate(hibernate 3.5.5)

Tags: java, hibernate, detachedcriteria

Looks like it does not work with ignorCase. 
The first assert returns true. Second - false. Any Ideas?

```
EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager) applicationContext.getBean("entityManager");
HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = entityManager.getHibernateTemplate();
int size = hibernateTemplate.find("from Source where caption like '%Вход%'").size();
System.out.println("By Query: " + size);
assertTrue(size > 0);

DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Source.class);
detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.like("caption", "Вход", MatchMode.ANYWHERE).ignoreCase());
List list = hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(detachedCriteria);
System.out.println("By DC: " + list.size());
assertTrue(list.size() > 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ilike("caption", "Вход", MatchMode.ANYWHERE)` instead of `like(..).ignoreCase()`

http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html

Answer (score 1):

Try `Restrictions.ilike` instead of `Restrictions.like`.

Answer (score 1):

On most databases (except Postgres) Hibernate executes case-insensitive `like` as `lower(caption) like ?`, where `?` is a result of `"%Вход%".toLowerCase()`. As you can see, in your case it can produce `false` only if results of database `lower()` are inconsistent with results of `String.toLowerCase()`. It can happen, for example, if database locale configuration doesn't support case conversion for Cyrillic characters.